# JAVA, MulticastSocket object questions :

Tags: java

Q1: ,  For the setTimeToLive method,( setTimeToLive(int ttl) ) what unit of time does the integer input parameter (ttl) represent? (milliseconds, seconds, ?))

Q2: if a particular MulticastSocket object is used to perform a send  (localMulticastSocket.send(datagramPacketToSend)) can the same object be used to perform a receive (localMultiCastSocket.receive(datagramPacketToReceive)), immediately afterward? FYI, I am sending a particular message to a card reader device, using a MulticastSocket object, and wish to to attempt to receive a response back from that device, using the same MulticastSocket object, if possible

just looking for some answers is all

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.